# calculating probability of sentence with Naive Bayes using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, naivebayes

I am looking at the source code for the naive bayes classifier in NLTK

```
http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html
```

where at the top they explain the way they calculate the probability.

I would like to understand, how this algorithm calculates the probabilities for my corpus.

I have (at the moment) about 500 text files with sentences labelled as positive and 198 labelled negative.

So the probability P(pos) is 500/619 and P(neg) ist 198/618. So far so good.

P(f1|label) would be the probability of a feature (in my case, a word) occuring in sentences labelled pos, right?

So if in my 500 text files, I have a total of 3000 unique words and 4500 words in all the sentences labelled ps and the word in question appears 70 times in sentences labelled pos, this probability would be 70+1/(3000+4500), right?

And then it says "Rather than computing P(featues) explicitly, the algorithm just
calculates the denominator for each label, and normalizes them so they
sum to one:
"

What is the purpuse of that? And what exactly does this `SUM[l]( P(l) * P(f1|l) * ... * P(fn|l) )` mean?

Given the sentence "This is a very dangerous effect" and it should be labelled as pos.
With the numbers used above, the probability for this sentence being pos would be:

(500/619) * P(this|pos) * (is|pos) * (a|pos)... etc. / (Whatever the sum(L) means)

is that correct?

And another question: I read here [Different results between the Bernoulli Naive Bayes in NLTK and in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732769/different-results-between-the-bernoulli-naive-bayes-in-nltk-and-in-scikit-learn) that NLTK uses a multinomial naive bayes. How can you tell that form the source code?

Comment: In case of Binomial Naive Bayes, you calculate the presence or absence of a feature in you positive or negative examples, while in Multinomial you calculate its probability using MLE.

Comment: @Riyaz Thanks for your reply! Do you know what the SUM[l]( P(l) * P(f1|l) * ... * P(fn|l) ) part means?